# How can I add an HTML/CSS alert when an else statement happens?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, socket.io

I want to add some of my HTML to my javascript, so when someone writes over 200 characters, it gives a popup that you can't write over 200 characters.

server.js:

```
  socket.on("message", function(message, callback, req) {
    if(message.text.length < 200) {
    message.timestamp = moment().valueOf();
    io.to(connectedUsers[socket.id].room).emit("message", message);
    } else {
      "Where the HTML/CSS will be"
    }
  });
```

HTML/CSS:

```
<style>
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
</style>
<div class="alert">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> 
  <strong>Warning!</strong> You cannot write over 200 characters.
</div>
```

So, when someone types over 200 characters this HTML/CSS will popup on their screen.

Comment: Why do you need to communicate with the server for this? This is a pure front-end problem, isn't it? Why not a simple popup/alert/modal?

Comment: How would I do that? I'm a beginner in HTML & CSS so I would have no clue.

Comment: `if( input.value.length > 200 ) alert("You can't type more than 200 characters")` :) I mean, you don't know how to do this, and you're already building chat rooms?? Maybe you should start with the basics first :)

Comment: I've already tried using alert but it just gives me an error that alert Isn't defined.

Comment: You have to add it to the client-side code, not in the nodeJS code. @JeremyThille all beginners now start with chat rooms and facial recognition, like we used to start with a minesweeper.. O tempora, o mores

Comment: Alert is not defined in NodeJS, because the code runs on the server, not in the browser... Real friendly and good advice, stop right where you are, start with really basic stuff, like what's the difference between a browser and a server (front-end and back-end)